# One Select, Two Resultsets: Returning Summary and Detail based on same query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm attempting to perform a large query where I want to:

1. Query the detail rows, then
2. Perform aggregations based on the results returned

Essentially, I want to perform my data-intensive query ONCE, and derive both summary and detail values from the one query, as the query is pretty intensive.  I'm SURE there is a better way to do this using the frontend application (e.g. detail rows in the SQL, aggregate in front-end?), but I want to know how to do this all in PL/SQL using essentially one select against the db (for performance reasons, I don't want to call essentially the same large Select twice)(and at this point, my reasons for wanting to do it in one query might be called stubborn... i.e. even if there's a better way, I'd like to know if it can be done).

I know how to get the basic "detail-level" resultset.  That query would return data such as:

UPC-Region-ProjectType-TotalAssignments-IncompleteAssignments

So say I have 10 records:

10-A-X-20-10

11-B-X-10-5

12-C-Y-30-15

13-C-Z-20-10

14-A-Y-10-5

15-B-X-30-15

16-C-Z-20-10

17-B-Y-10-5

18-C-Z-30-15

19-A-X-20-10

20-B-X-10-5

I want to be able to perform the query, then perform aggregations on that resultset, such as:

Region A Projects: 3

Region A Total Assign: 50

Region A Incompl Assign: 25

Region B...

Region C...

Project Type X Projects: 5

Project Type X Total Assign: 90

Project Type X Incompl Assign: 45

Project Type Y...

Project Type Z...

And then return both resultsets (Summary + Detail) to the calling application.

I guess the idea would be running the Details query into a Temp Table, and then selecting/performing aggregation on it there to build the second "summary level" query.  then passing the two resultsets back as two refcursors.

But I'm open to ideas...

My initial attempts have been:

```
type rec_projects is record
   (record matching my DetailsSQL)

/* record variable */
project_resultset rec_projects;

/* cursor variable */
OPEN cursorvar1 FOR
  select 
    upc,
    region,
    project_type,
    tot_assigns,
    incompl_assigns
    ...
```

Then I:

```
loop
  fetch cursorvar1 into project_resultset;  
  exit when cursorvar1%NOTFOUND;

  /* perform row-by-row aggregations into variables */
  If project_resultset.region = 'A'
  then
    numAProj        := numAProj + 1;
    numATotalAssign := numATotalAssign + project_resultset.Totassigns;
    numAIncomplAssign := numAIncomplAssign + project_resultset.Incomplassigns;
  and so on...

 end loop;
```

Followed by opening another refcursor var - selecting the variables from DUAL:

```
open cursorvar2 for
  select
     numAProj, numATotalAssign, numAIncomplAssign, etc, etc from dual;
```

Lastly:

```
cur_out1 := cursorvar1;
cur_out2 := cursorvar2;
```

not working... cursorvar1 seems to load fine, and I get into the loop.  But I'm not ending up with anything in cursorvar2, and just feel I'm probably totally on the wrong path here (that there is a better way to do it)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer doing all calculations on server side.
Both types of information (detail + master) can be fetched through single cursor:

```
with
   DET as (
      -- your details subquery here
      select
         UPC,
         Region,
         Project_Type,
         Total_Assignments,
         Incomplete_Assignments
      from ...
   )
select
   UPC,
   Region,
   Project_Type,
   Total_Assignments,
   Incomplete_Assignments,
   null as projects_ctr
from DET

union all

select
   null as UPC,
   Region,
   null as Project_Type,
   sum(Total_Assignments) as Total_Assignments,
   sum(Incomplete_Assignments) as Incomplete_Assignments,
   count(0) as projects_ctr
from DET
group by Region

union all

select
   null as UPC,
   null as Region,
   Project_Type,
   sum(Total_Assignments) as Total_Assignments,
   sum(Incomplete_Assignments) as Incomplete_Assignments,
   count(0) as projects_ctr
from DET
group by Project_Type

order by UPC nulls first, Region, Project_Type
```

Result:

```
UPC     Region  Project_Type  Total_Assignments  Incomplete_Assignments  Projects_Ctr
------  ------  ------------  -----------------  ----------------------  ------------
(null)  A       (null)        50                 25                      3
(null)  B       (null)        60                 30                      4
(null)  C       (null)        100                50                      4
(null)  (null)  X             90                 45                      5
(null)  (null)  Y             50                 25                      3
(null)  (null)  Z             70                 35                      3
10      A       X             20                 10                      (null)
11      B       X             10                 5                       (null)
12      C       Y             30                 15                      (null)
13      C       Z             20                 10                      (null)
14      A       Y             10                 5                       (null)
15      B       X             30                 15                      (null)
16      C       Z             20                 10                      (null)
17      B       Y             10                 5                       (null)
18      C       Z             30                 15                      (null)
19      A       X             20                 10                      (null)
20      B       X             10                 5                       (null)
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/81f21/2)

Comment: Egor, you are the MAN!  Very impressive... thanks a million.  I was newly familiar with "WITH" from my current bedtime reading (Mastering Oracle SQL from O'Reilly), but obviously still learning how to use that...  now I know one cool thing to do with it, thanks to you.

Comment: Funny, I'm just re-checking the above mentioned book.  In a section entitled "global inline views" it talks about the "with" clause.  It says with the "WITH" clause, the inline view is visible everywhere within the query.  Then I had the following **highlighted in orange **: "This makes the WITH clause inline view act more like a temporary table than a true inline view".  Apparently, highlighting still doesn't help it sink in...  Still, sometimes it helps to have someone show you.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be creating these reports regularly, it might be better to create a global temporary table to store the results of your initial query:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE MY_TEMP_TABLE
    ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS 
    AS 
        SELECT 
            UPC,
            Region,
            ProjectType,
            TotalAssignments,
            IncompleteAssignments 
        FROM WHEREVER
;
```

You can then run a series of follow-up queries to calculate the various statistics values for your report and output them in a format other than a large text table.